# Ist vor + Akkusativ manchmal möglich und wünschenswert?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-case, dative

Der Online-Übersetzer gibt mir die folgende Übersetzung

> Die Klimakrise verschlimmert sich und stellt uns vor zahlreiche ökologische,soziale und wirtschaftliche Herausforderungen

Ich verstehe, dass bei *stellen vor* sozusagen eine Bewegung ausgedrückt wird, weiß aber auch vom Schulbuch aus, dass *vor* immer mit Dativ aufgebaut wird.

Ist der Satz richtig ? Sollte es eher so sein:

> Die Klimakrise verschlimmert sich und stellt uns vor zahlreichen ökologischen, sozialen und wirtschaftlichen Herausforderungen

Comment: _Das Klima geht vor die Hunde_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Annahme, daß *vor* immer mit Dativ benutzt wird, ist falsch. *Vor* ist eine Präposition, die je nach Kontext Dativ oder Akkusativ verlangt.

> *Ich stehe vor dem Haus.* (stationärer Ort, Dativ)

> *Ich gehe vor das Haus.* (Richtung/Bewegung, Akkusativ)

Nur der erste Beispielsatz aus der Frage mit Akkusativ ist richtig, der zweite ist falsch. Man könnte den Satz aber umformulieren, so daß Dativ verlangt wird:

> Die Klimakrise verschlimmert sich, und wir stehen vor zahlreichen ökologischen,
> sozialen und wirtschaftlichen Herausforderungen.

Comment: Bitte kein code-Format verwenden! Das ist für Telefone wirklich übel und ja auch nur notwendig, wenn die code-Zeilen strukturiert werden sollen.